# Prevent hitting child states ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is what i have so far with ui-router states:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('tools', {
    url: '/tools/:tool',
    template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
    abstract: true,
    onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, TOOL_TYPES) {
      if (TOOL_TYPES.indexOf($stateParams.tool) === -1) {
        $state.go('error');
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tools.list', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'app/tools/tools.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ToolsController'
  })
  .state('tools.view', {
    url: '/:id/view',
    templateUrl: 'app/tools/partials/tool.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ToolController'
  });
```

As you can see parent state has parameter `tool` which can be only in `TOOL_TYPES` array. So in case when `tool` is not available, i want to redirect to the error page.

Actually, everything works as expected, but i get two errors:

`TypeError: Cannot read property '@' of null`

`TypeError: Cannot read property '@tools' of null`

So i guess, child states have been 'hit' anyway. Is it possible to prevent this? Or maybe there is some other way to achieve what i want?

Comment: I think it might be a known issue with ui-router. Check this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1434 and this: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1234 out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[Angular ui-router's](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#user-content-onenter-and-onexit-callbacks)** documentation mentions that `onEnter` callbacks gets called when a state becomes active, hence, the child states were activated.

To solve this problem you need to implement two things:

1. Create a `resolve` that returns a rejected promise once a specific condition does not apply to that state. Make sure that the rejected promise is passed with information regarding the state to redirect to.
2. Create a `$stateChangeError` event handler in the `$rootScope` and use the 6th parameter which is the representation of the information you have passed in the rejected promise. Use the information to create your redirect implementation.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GreZdN7zZB16I5tHpWjg?p=preview)**

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

  .value('TOOL_TYPES', [
    'tool1', 'tool2', 'tool3'
  ])

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

      .state('error', {
        url: '/error',
        template: 'Error!'
      })

      .state('tools', {
        url: '/tools/:tool',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',
        resolve: {
          tool_type: function($state, $q, $stateParams, TOOL_TYPES) {

            var index = TOOL_TYPES.indexOf($stateParams.tool);

            if(index === -1) {
              return $q.reject({
                state: 'error'
              });
            }

            return TOOL_TYPES[index];
          }
        }
      })

      .state('tools.list', {
        url: '',
        template: 'List of Tools',
        controller: 'ToolsController'
      })
      .state('tools.view', {
        url: '/:id/view',
        template: 'Tool View',
        controller: 'ToolController'
      });

  })

  .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(
      event, toState, toStateParams, 
      fromState, fromStateParams, error) {

        if(error && error.state) {
          $state.go(error.state, error.params, error.options);
        }

    });
  })

  .controller('ToolsController', function() {})
  .controller('ToolController', function() {});
```